# Thrust: summing the elements of an array indexed by another array [Matlab's syntax sum(x(indices))]

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to sum the elements of an array indexed by another array using the Thrust library, but I couldn't find an example. In other words, I want to implement Matlab's syntax

```
sum(x(indices))
```

Here is a guideline code trying to point out what do I like to achieve:

```
#define N 65536

// device array copied using cudaMemcpyToSymbol
__device__ int global_array[N];

// function to implement with thrust
__device__ int support(unsigned short* _memory, unsigned short* _memShort)
{
   int support = 0;

  for(int i=0; i < _memSizeShort; i++)
        support += global_array[_memory[i]];

  return support;     
}
```

Also, from the host code, can I use the **global_array[N]** without copying it back with **cudaMemcpyFromSymbol** ?

Every comment/answer is appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do? Is the sum an overall sum (ie. is your `support` function supposed to be a fused gather-reduction) or is it something else? Is there some reason you have chosen to show `support` as a device function, or is that basically irrelevant?

Comment: If you use Thrust you should code in a proper C++ style, IMO.

Comment: @talonmies  you solved my problem just saying "fused gather-reduction" !! It is exactly what I was looking for! But a couple of things: from the example in *Thrust Quick Start Guide* (permutation_iterator),  they are just iterating the wholes arrays. Instead of it, I'd like to iterate for a certain number (as the for loop above); how can I do that ? And, should I copy back the global_array[N] from the device ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late answer provided here to remove this question from the unanswered list. I'm sure that the OP has already found a solution (since May 2012 :-)), but I believe that the following could be useful to other users.

As pointed out by @talonmies, the problem can be solved by a fused gather-reduction. The solution is indeed an application of Thurst's `permutation_iterator` and `reduce`. The `permutation_iterator` allows to (implicitly) reorder the target array `x` according to the indices in the `indices` array. `reduce` performs the sum of the (implicitly) reordered array.

This application is part of [Thrust's documentation](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/permutation_iterator.cu), below reported for convenience

```
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

// this example fuses a gather operation with a reduction for
// greater efficiency than separate gather() and reduce() calls

int main(void)
{
    // gather locations
    thrust::device_vector<int> map(4);
    map[0] = 3;
    map[1] = 1;
    map[2] = 0;
    map[3] = 5;

    // array to gather from
    thrust::device_vector<int> source(6);
    source[0] = 10;
    source[1] = 20;
    source[2] = 30;
    source[3] = 40;
    source[4] = 50;
    source[5] = 60;

    // fuse gather with reduction: 
    //   sum = source[map[0]] + source[map[1]] + ...
    int sum = thrust::reduce(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(source.begin(), map.begin()),
                             thrust::make_permutation_iterator(source.begin(), map.end()));

    // print sum
    std::cout << "sum is " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, `map` plays the role of `indices`, while `source` plays the role of `x`.

Concerning the additional question in your comment (iterating over a reduced number of terms), it will be sufficient to change the following line

```
int sum = thrust::reduce(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(source.begin(), map.begin()),
                         thrust::make_permutation_iterator(source.begin(), map.end()));
```

to

```
int sum = thrust::reduce(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(source.begin(), map.begin()),
                         thrust::make_permutation_iterator(source.begin(), map.begin()+N));
```

if you want to iterate only over the first `N` terms of the indexing array `map`.

Finally, concerning the possibility of using `global_array` from the host, you should notice that this is a vector residing on the device, so you do need a `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` to move it to the host first.